# SQL table / view designer in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, runtime

I am developing an application that requires "some" customization by the enduser afecting the database design (beyond the parametrization).

Now a days this application supports to work with new columns for the existing tables or even new tables in runtime. But the enduser is not capable to alter the tables, and all the design work must be done using Microsoft SQL Server Magament Studio.

My question is: *there is any kind of control (or tool) which implements this functionality?* I would like to have it embeded in my application, but if it is a external tool wouldn't be so bad.

What I want to have is some tool that let the user define a repository of columns (name, type, size) for example:

- CustomerCode, BIGINT, n/a
- CustomerName, Varchar, 50

And then create or alter a table or view by adding these predefined columns. And underneath should execute the needed SQL script or maybe using SMO (SQL Management Objects).

**Updated**

Currently it's the application works with WinForms, but any WPF / ASP solution would be appreciated.

And referring to and enduser I mean a app administrator but not with programing skills.

**Purpouse**

The purpose is to be able to extend and customize the functionality from the own apllication without having to use SQL Server Managment Studio.

Imagine that you have an ERP, as a user you want to inform in your customers table something that the application was not orginally intended and even has no free fields for it, for example: GPS location, logo, CEO's photo...

Of course I can suggest to some advanced users to install SSMS Express, but that will give them too much freedom. I also think it is a IT tool. What I wanted is to develop the capability to modify the application from the own framework of the application.

If it can be done from the own application, some controls can be performed:

- Check that a table field called X will be always defined with the same type,
- Disable the capability to modify the non-customizable fields (application fields),
- ...

Comment: WPF, ASP.Net, Silverlight or Winforms?

Comment: Do you think is a good idea let someone without the know-how change the database design? Can you tell us the rules to do that? Like, can the user remove table or columns also? Can the user add/alter/drop indexes?

Comment: i agree with @BrunoCosta we really need more info for this. what you are saying is not standard practice at all. it seems like you need to gather requirements from the user because what you think might be a solution, may not at all fit their needs

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов I hope this new update will be usefull

Comment: @BrunoCosta I don't pretend this capability to modify the database be open to all the user, only to the advanced/key-users.

Comment: @Alex Those "advanced/key-users", do they know what to do with it? If so, why not just create an account with restrict access to those users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this kind of control does not exists, so I will scratch it from 0.

@BrunoCosta's idea of using an EAV model to extend the standard application is a good practice. But I pretend to have a tool to modify the standard, and have a tool used for the final user and also for the developer. A pseudo SQL Server Studio + Visual Studio embedded in the a application.

Once I develop it, I will to post it in CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

Alex, I think you should try to give the user the flexibility to add new information to the database without really change the design of the database.

You can take a look at EAV Model (entity-attribute-value). This give you the flexibilty to add any new attribute to customer without change the design of customer table (e.g.).

One good example is Magento, they did a great job with EAV (entity-attribute-value) but you must  know that this design model will hit your performance a little (or a lot depends how you implement it).

Answer (score -1):

I think that the control you are looking for may be a little too unique. However, I don't think it would be too difficult create this yourself using other controls/libraries.

I am just finishing up a similar WPF project.
I found that the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y0) class worked well for representing a table. You can add/remove columns programmatically. Although you would be generating the SQL script yourself.

Comment: @Артём Царионов: The customization is possible, but would have to be implemented.

Comment: It's not exacly what I wanted, I'm lookig for something more like SQL Server Magment environment

Comment: @Alex you can give them SSMS just restrict their privileges